# Unity login screen for GNOME

Tags: lightdm, ubuntu-gnome

I'm currently using Ubuntu GNOME 16.10. I love the GNOME DE. I like it much better than Unity. But the one thing I like about Unity is the login screen. I know it's possible to get LightDM for GNOME, but can I get it to be exactly like the login screen for Ubuntu?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, if you change from the gdm3 display manager to the lightdm display manager, you'll get back your favorite login screen again.

In `terminal`:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm
```

and choose lightdm.

For more info about this command, see `man dpkg-reconfigure`.